# Somar valor anterior com o atual (FOREACH - PHP)

Tags: php

A minha dúvida é bem simples.

**Problema:** tenho um laço de repetição foreach, e nesse laço de repetição eu separo as datas ($dados['DATA'] é onde separo) e a cada valor encontrado ele deve somar o valor atual com o anterior da mesma data (pois são muitos registros no mesmo dia), meu problema é que eu não estou conseguindo pegar o valor anterior dessa mesma data.

Exemplo:

```
foreach ($indices as $dados)
  {
      $retorno['semana'][$dados['DATA']][] = calcula(count($dados['NOTA']-1), $dados['NOTA']);
  }
```

Função Calcula:

```
function calculaHoras($valor_anterior, $valor_atual)
{
  $resultado = $valor_anterior + $valor_atual;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para um laço de repetição pegar o valor anterior para salvar, temos o seguinte exemplo

```
$valorInicial = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $valorInicial = $valorInicial + $value;
}
```

Assim vc estaria sempre atualizando o valor inicial com a soma.

Neste seu caso pelo que entendi ficaria assim

```
$valorInicial = 0;
foreach($indices as $dados) {
   $valorInicial = $valorInicial + $dados['NOTA'];
}
$retorno['semana'][$dados['DATA']][] = $valorInicial;
```